# How is a block defined in solana terminology

Tags: slots, block

As I understand a slot is period of time a pre-determined leader ingests transactions, signs them , distributes it to the validators to vote on them, technically there is no delay between a leader recieving several tx bundling them into entries ( i.e signing and attaching poh hash) and distributing it to validators to validate and vote upon, so how is a block defined then ? what is the block space limit in solana terminology, for example ethereum has a gas limit , max 30 million gas limit per block.

Comment: I'll answer the "what is a block" part here.  please move the question about the limit to its own post and reword this one

Answer (score 9):

A `slot` is a period of time where the predetermined leader *may* propose a bundle of transactions that it attests to being valid as per consensus.  Whether that bundle ends up being a `block` depends upon whether

- the scheduled leader actually produced a bundle at that slot
- the bundle is in fact valid per the current consensus rules
- the bundle was built upon the majority fork